# How to stop excel from changing formula to referenced column range?

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

Not sure if my terminology is correct but the problem is that I have a vba module that I am using to analyze data(count unique values). The formula is fine and works when after I correct excels change.

VBA line to insert formula is

```
ws_MachineNumber.Range("D2").FormulaLocal = _
            "=SUM(IF('Roh Daten_IA'!$B$2:$B$" & lastR_RDi & "= A2, 1/(COUNTIFS('Roh Daten_IA'!$B$2:$B$" & lastR_RDi & ",MachineNumber!A2,'Roh Daten_IA'!$G$2:$G$" & lastR_RDi & ",'Roh Daten_IA'!$G$2:$G$" & lastR_RDi & ")),0))"
```

Which I am expecting to show up in the cell as

```
=SUM(IF('Roh Daten_IA'!$B$2:$B$296= A2, 1/(COUNTIFS('Roh Daten_IA'!$B$2:$B$296,MachineNumber!A2,'Roh Daten_IA'!$G$2:$G$296,'Roh Daten_IA'!$G$2:$G$296)),0))
```

However for a reason unbeknownst to me excel keeps making it

```
=SUM(IF(@'Roh Daten_IA'!$B$2:$B$296= A2, 1/(COUNTIFS('Roh Daten_IA'!$B$2:$B$296,MachineNumber!A2,'Roh Daten_IA'!$G$2:$G$296,@'Roh Daten_IA'!$G$2:$G$296)),0))
```

not sure why it keeps referencing it that way. Prior to this I didn't have the abs ranges and figured that was the problem but the @ symbol is somehow causing the formula to operate incorrectly and it gives a result of 0 for every occurrence regardless of what the correct evaluation should give.

Thank you

Comment: What happens if you change `FormulaLocal` to `Formula`?

Comment: Did you try using `FormulaR1C1`? You can easily get you formula recorded as R1C1 notation just using your macro recorder

Comment: I typically use ```formulalocal``` because sometimes the code may be used in German version of excel so using ```formulalocal``` just auto corrects the language. I've used this setup multiple times but this is the first time that I've seen the addition of the @ symbol.